# Загрузка файлов

Tags: php

Добрый день, Нужно сделать загрузку файлов с описанием, каждого прикреплённого файла. И общее описание всех файлов. Как это реализовать.

Нужно загружать неопрелеенное колличество файлов. Ну и к каждому нужно описание.

```
function reArrayFiles($file)
{
$file_ary = [];
$file_count = count($file['name']);
$file_key = array_keys($file);

for($i=0;$i<$file_count;$i++)
{
    foreach($file_key as $val)
    {
        $file_ary[$i][$val] = $file[$val][$i];
    }
}
return $file_ary;
}


if(!empty($_FILES['img'])){

$img = $_FILES['img'];
$img_desc = reArrayFiles($img);

$event=mb_substr(sha1(date('YmdHis')), 0,5);
$directory="img/"."$event"."/";
mkdir($directory,0777,true);
chmod($directory, 0777);

foreach($img_desc as $val)
{
    $newname = 
mb_substr(sha1(date('YmdHis',time()).mt_rand()),0,7).'.jpg';
    move_uploaded_file($val['tmp_name'],$directory.$newname);
    chmod($directory.'/'.$newname, 0777);
    }
}



<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>
<form method="post" action="formfiles.php" enctype="multipart/form-
data">
file :  <input type="file" name="img[]" multiple>
<input type="submit"  />
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Под описанием имеется ввиду текст к файлу и файлам, который должен быть введён пользователем в какой-либо TextBox?

Comment: Описание каждого файла это  alternate к фото. А всех фото это просто текст. Такая себе контент форма .

Comment: Загружаете файлы, а рядом файл с массивом, где ключ массива - это название файла, а значение, нужное описание. Все просто.

Answer (score 1):

Не гуру программирования, но вот что в голову пришло.

HTML

```html
<form method="post" action="formfiles.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <!-- Добавляем id к input -->
    <input id="fileload_input" type="file" name="img[]" multiple />
    <!-- Добавляем контейнер для описания каждого файла -->
    <div id="desc"></div>
    <!-- Добавляем TextArea для описания всех файлов -->
    <textarea type="text" name="description"></textarea>
    <input type="submit"  />
</form>
```

JQuery

```js
//Вешаем обработчик на каждое изменение формы загрузки файлов
$(document).on("change","#fileload_input", function () {
    //Очищаем контейнер описаловок для файлов
    var container = $('#desc');
    container.html("");
    //Получаем все файлы
    var files = this.files;
    var count_files = files.length;
    //Добавляем поля для описания файлов
    //Ключевое здесь - это name у input, с точно такими же id что и у файлов
    for (var i = 0; i<count_files; i++)
    {
        //Сам input
        var elem = '<input type="text" id="desc['+ i +']" name="desc['+ i +']" />';
        //Label для него
        var desc = '<label for="desc['+ i +']">Описание для '+ files[i].name +' </label>'
        //Добавляем элементы в контейнер
        container.append(desc);
        container.append(elem);
    }
});
```

PHP

```php
if(!empty($_FILES['img']) && !empty($_POST['desc']) && !empty($_POST['description'])){
    //Сами файлы
    $img = $_FILES['img'];
    //Массив описаний для каждого файла
    $desc = $_POST['desc'];
    //Общее описание всех файлов
    $description = $_POST['description'];

    //Далее воротим как хотим...


}
```